# error after changing the app name

Tags: android, libgdx

I have made a game in Libgdx(eclipse).I changed the name of the app inside the
string.xml file.Now I have an error in AndroidManifest.xml. in this line:
  android:label="@string/app_name"‬ (line 12).
its written:" No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name')."
what is the solution?